# Image grid carousel not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-moving-box-carousel

This code is not working properly.

I think the CSS and JavaScript links are not working properly.

Comment: can u provide us with your code? an actual example (codepen or jsfiddle) with what problems you are having or what have you tried?

Comment: Please try to edit your question properly with code

Comment: provide your code so that we can help you :)

Comment: please check above link css and js were problem in that code sir

Comment: the link above is working fine, what error do you get @Sampath Kumar ?

Comment: Actually the page everything is fine but js not affecting to that page. that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use boostrap link 3.3.7 instead of 3.3.0:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```